# Event listener on AJAX form only fires before form is submitted

Tags: javascript, ajax, addeventlistener

I have a form that on submit sends an AJAX request. That part is working fine.

I have a date field in the form that has a change event listener. This works fine the first time the page loads. After the form is submitted once, the change event no longer fires.

```js
const date = document.querySelector('.latest-news__date');
if (date) {

  date.addEventListener('change', function () {
    // Only fires before the form is submitted. 
  });
}
```

How can I make this fire even after the form is submitted?

Comment: Are you sure the page is not reloading?

Comment: Yes, I am sure the page is not reloading. If I reload the page, the event listener works.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Drupal and didn't realize that I have to add some drupal code around my JS to make this work. https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

```js
Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
  attach: function () {
    const date = document.querySelector('.latest-news__date');
    if (date) {

      date.addEventListener('change', function () {
        // This will now fire even after the submit button is clicked.
      });
    }
  },
};
```